# Number of Dyck Paths Bounded by $M$

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

A Dyck path of length $2k$ is a sequence $\{s_j\}_{j=1}^{2k}$ of non-negative integers such that $|s_{j+1} - s_j| = 1$ for all $j = 1,...,2k$ and $s_0 = s_{2k} = 0$. The number of Dyck paths of length $2k$ is given by the nice formula
$$C_k = \frac{1}{k+1}\begin{pmatrix} 2k\\k\end{pmatrix}.$$

($C_k$ is the $k$-th Catalan number.)

Given some positive integer $M$, is there a formula for the number of all Dyck paths of length $2k$ such that $s_{j} \le M$ for all $j = 1,...,2k$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is essentially [OEIS A080934](https://oeis.org/A080934), in which $T(n,k)$ is the number of Dyck paths of length $2n$ with all values less than or equal to $k$.

Suppose that such a path of length $2n+2$ last hits the $x$-axis at $\langle 2i,0\rangle$, where $0\le i\le n$; clearly there are $T(i,k)$ possibilities for the path from $\langle 0,0\rangle$ to $\langle 2i,0\rangle$. The first step after that must be an up-step, to $\langle 2i+1,1\rangle$, the last step must be a down-step, from $\langle 2n-1,1\rangle$ to $\langle 2n+2,0\rangle$, and between $\langle 2i+1,1\rangle$ and $\langle 2n+1,1\rangle$ the path cannot drop below the line $y=1$. Thus, the path from $\langle 2i+1,1\rangle$ to $\langle 2n+1,1\rangle$ must be one of the $T(n-i,k-1)$ paths from $\langle 0,0\rangle$ to $\langle 2(n-i),0\rangle$ that don’t rise above the line $y=k-1$, but shifted $2i+1$ units to the right and one unit up. It follows that

$$T(n+1,k)=\sum_{i=0}^nT(i,k)T(n-i,k-1)\;.\tag{1}$$

The initial conditions are $T(0,k)=1$ for all $k\in\Bbb N$ and $T(n,0)=[n=0]$, where the bracket is an [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). (The recurrence $(1)$ is given in the OEIS entry, but with the wrong limits on the summation.) A closed form does not seem to be known; here are the first few values.

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
k\backslash n&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\ \hline
0&\color{red}{1}&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&\\
1&1&\color{red}{1}&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&\\
2&1&1&\color{red}{2}&4&8&16&32&64&128&256&\\
3&1&1&2&\color{red}{5}&13&34&89&233&610&1597&\\
4&1&1&2&5&\color{red}{14}&41&122&365&1094&3281&\\
5&1&1&2&5&14&\color{red}{42}&131&417&1341&4334&\\
6&1&1&2&5&14&42&\color{red}{132}&428&1416&4744&\\
7&1&1&2&5&14&42&132&\color{red}{429}&1429&4846&\\
8&1&1&2&5&14&42&132&429&\color{red}{1430}&4861&\\
9&1&1&2&5&14&42&132&429&1430&\color{red}{4862}
\end{array}$$

The diagonal and everything below it is of course the Catalan numbers. The first four rows of the table are familiar ($T(n,3)=F_{2n-1}$). The OEIS entry has generating functions for the rows.

[OEIS A080936](https://oeis.org/A080936) gives the number of Dyck paths of length $2n$ and height exactly $k$ and has a little more information on the generating functions.

Comment: @BrianMScott: Very nice explanation! +1