# Tighter bound for the total number of possible $m$-ary tree with $n$ nodes and maximum height $h$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inequality, graph-theory, trees

I know that the total number of possible $m$-ary tree with $n$ nodes is
\begin{align}
C_n&=\frac{1}{(m-1)n+1}{mn \choose n},
\end{align}
which is the Catalan number. I want to know if I can get a tighter (in the binomial coefficient) bound for the total number of possible $m$-ary tree with $n$ nodes if I restrict the maximum height of the tree to $h$ -- i.e., trees can be of height $h$ or less.

**Note:** I am aware of the bijection between $m$-ary trees and $(m-1)$-dyck paths. From Brian M. Scott's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569899/number-of-dyck-paths-bounded-by-m?rq=1), there does not seem to be a closed form for the number of bounded dyck paths. I was wondering if I could get a upper bound on that number that is tighter (in the binomial coefficient term) than the Catalan number?