# Number of Dyck paths with bounded height and fixed number of peaks

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, recursion

The number of Dyck paths of length $2n$ and exactly $k$ peaks is given by the Narayana numbers:
\begin{equation}
 \frac{1}{n} {n\choose k}{n \choose k-1}
\end{equation}

In a [OEIS A080934](https://oeis.org/A080934), a recurrence relation is given for the number of Dyck paths with maximum height less than or equal to $h$, as well as a closed form solution. Looking at the same logic as in a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569899/number-of-dyck-paths-bounded-by-m?rq=1), it seems that the number of Dyck paths with halflength $n$, $k$ peaks and bounded in height by $h$ (call it $H(n,k,h)$) should obey the recursion relation
\begin{equation}
H(n+1,k,h) = \sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^i H(i,j,h)H(n-i,k-j,h-1)
\end{equation}
With a few initial conditions such as $H(0,k,h) = \delta_{k0}$, $H(n,0,h) = \delta_{n0}$, $H(n,k,0) = \delta_{n0}\delta_{k0}$ .
From this recursion relation, is it possible to derive a trivariate generating function $G(x,y,z) = \sum_{x,y,z}H(n,k,h)x^ny^kz^h$, or even a closed form solution for H (though that might be optimistic)?

Edit: I previously had the wrong bounds on the sum, we must include the possibility of the first return being the empty path

Answer (score 1):

Consider the bivariate generating function, where we keep $h$ fixed:
$$
F_h(x,y)=\sum_{n,m\ge 0}H(n,k,h)x^ny^k
$$
By decomposing a Dyck path with height at most $h$ into the times when it returns to the $x$ axis, we see that a path with height $h$ is an ordered sequence of paths with height $h-1$. If you sum (length + 1) over all sub-paths, you get the length of the whole path. If you sum the peaks of the sub-paths, you get the total number of peaks, with one exception; an empty path has zero peaks, but it contributes on peak to the total.

Translating all this to generating function language,
$$
F_h(x,y)=\frac1{1-x(F_{h-1}(x,y)-1+y)}
$$
Unfortunately, I do not see how to derive the trivariate generating function you mentioned. However, you can prove by induction that $F_h$ can be written in the form
$$
F_h(x,y)=\frac{P_h(x,y)}{Q_h(x,y)}
$$
for some polynomials $P_h,Q_h$.

Comment: Interesting, to clarify: if we were to find a closed form for $F_h$ in terms of $h$, this would be equivalent to having found $G$, correct? As an aside, it seems unlikely that this problem has not been looked at before, however I cannot find anything about it

Comment: @Olivier You have $G=\sum_{h\ge 0} F_h(x,y)z^h$, so a closed form for $F_h$ gives a summation form for $G$, though not a closed one. I suppose I can believe no one has considered it before. Certainly, Dyck paths with bounded height (no peak restriction) have been studied, see [the average height of planted planar trees](https://research.tue.nl/en/publications/the-average-height-of-planted-plane-trees-2) (and recall Dyck paths = planar trees).