# Passenger entrance/exit combinations

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

In question is:

> The number of possible ways a vehicle with capacity $K$ can pickup and
> drop off $n$ passengers in a single tour, while each passenger has an
> individual pickup and dropoff location.

Combinatorically, this seems to relate to both [A000680](https://oeis.org/A000680) and [A080934](https://oeis.org/A080934).

A000680 has the very simple and quite intutive formula $\frac{(2n)!}{2^{n}}$. This would be the number of valid entrance and exit sequences in a vehicle with *unlimited* capacity  (ruling out all exit before entrance combinations). Alternatively, it could be modeled as the number of lattice walks in an n-dimensional lattice $(\mathbb{Z_{2}})^n$.

A080934 on the other hand limits the height of a dyck path. Also, for sequences of balanced parenthesss, this would mean the number of parentheses sequences of maximum depth $k$. For instance, `(()()())` has depth 2, while `(((())))` has depth 4. So, in the lattice example, it would be the number of subdiagonal walks in a two-dimensional lattice with distance from root location bounded by $k$. A recursive definition of this is explained in detail [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569899/number-of-dyck-paths-bounded-by-m). It is not completely congruent to my problem, since the bracket pairs are not distinguishable here.

Combining these together while staying in the lattice context, my formula should also be a calculation rule for the number of possible walks in $(\mathbb{Z_{2}})^n$ where the manhattan/hamming distance from the root location is bounded by $K$.

I even computationally filtered valid sequences for different values of $k$ and $n$ and searched OEIS for hours but only found sequences with small overlaps. Here is what I got for $k$, $n$ in the value range [0..5]:

$
\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
 k\backslash n& 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ \hline
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 6 & 24 & 120\\
 2 & 1 & 1 & 6 & 54 & 648 & 9720\\
 3 & 1 & 1 & 6 & 90 & 1944 & 52920\\
 4 & 1 & 1 & 6 & 90 & 2520 & 99000\\
 5 & 1 & 1 & 6 & 90 & 2520 & 113400\\
\end{array}
$

The diagonal matches $\frac{(2n)!}{2^{n}}$ (A000680), as the capacity is not a limiting factor here. The first row is simply $n!$, since only one can be in the vehicle.

Comment: [OEIS A034001](https://oeis.org/A034001) starting $1, 6, 54, 648, 9720, \ldots$  and [OEIS A071798](https://oeis.org/A071798) starting $0, 2, 54, 1944, 99000, \ldots$ also seems to appear in your table

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I have come across A071798, but now I can make sense of it: It matches the shifted diagonal where $n = k + 1$ and this corresponds to avoiding to reach the point $(1,1,...,1)$ in  $(\mathbb{Z_{2}})^n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can give a method of calculation: consider

$$f_k(c,n)=n\,f_k(c+1,n-1)+c\, f_k(c-1,n)$$

but with $f_k(c,n)=0$ if $n<0$ or $c<0$ or $c>k$ and starting with $f_k(0,0)=1$,

designed to have $f_k(c,n)$ representing the number of ways of handling $c$ passengers already in the vehicle of capacity $k$ with $n$ people waiting to be transported, meaning that that $f_k(0,n)$ gives the values you want.

For example, with $k=4$, you get the following table for $f_4(c,n)$

$
\begin{array}{c|ccccccccc}
c \backslash n & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 1 & 6 & 90 & 2520 & 99000 & 4806000 & 274050000 & 17886960000 \\ 
1 & 1 & 3 & 30 & 630 & 19800 & 801000 & 39150000 & 2235870000 & 145983600000 \\ 
2 & 2 & 12 & 180 & 4320 & 140400 & 5724000 & 280260000 & 16012080000 & 1045548000000 \\ 
3 & 6 & 60 & 1020 & 25200 & 824400 & 33660000 & 1648620000 & 94197600000 & 6150967200000 \\ 
4 & 24 & 240 & 4080 & 100800 & 3297600 & 134640000 & 6594480000 & 376790400000 & 24603868800000 \\ \end{array}
$

where $f_4(2,4)=4\,f_4(2+1,4-1) +2 \,f_4(2-1,4)  = 4\times25200 +2 \times 19800 = 140400$.

So using the resulting $f_k(0,n)$ you can easily expand your table, starting with

$
\begin{array}{c|ccccccccc}
k \backslash n & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\   
1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 6 & 24 & 120 & 720 & 5040 & 40320 \\ 
2 & 1 & 1 & 6 & 54 & 648 & 9720 & 174960 & 3674160 & 88179840 \\ 
3 & 1 & 1 & 6 & 90 & 1944 & 52920 & 1730160 & 65998800 & 2877275520 \\ 
4 & 1 & 1 & 6 & 90 & 2520 & 99000 & 4806000 & 274050000 & 17886960000 \\ 
5 & 1 & 1 & 6 & 90 & 2520 & 113400 & 6966000 & 525042000 & 46022256000 \\ 
6 & 1 & 1 & 6 & 90 & 2520 & 113400 & 7484400 & 655678800 & 70146518400 \\ 
7 & 1 & 1 & 6 & 90 & 2520 & 113400 & 7484400 & 681080400 & 80103945600 \\ 
8 & 1 & 1 & 6 & 90 & 2520 & 113400 & 7484400 & 681080400 & 81729648000 \\ \end{array}
$

Comment: Thanks alot, this is brilliant!

Comment: Can we upload this to OEIS?

Comment: @lukro - It is at [A368028](https://oeis.org/A368028), though I may have confused $n$ and $k$

Comment: Do you think it is possible to generalize the known factorial-based sequences(at least for $c=0$)? Currently, any $f_k(0,n)$ with k >= n is defined with $\frac{(2n)!}{2^{n}}$. For the shifted diagonal ($k = n-1$), it is $\frac{(2n)!}{2^{n}} - (n!)^2$. 

On the other hand the scenario $k=1$ (with $c=0$) is generally given by $n!$, $k=2$ by $\frac{3^{n}n!}{3}$. I could not yet continue this pattern.